# Excel VBA Pivot table - Fastest way to refresh pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, refresh

I'm using 1 Slicer from a pivot table containing sheet names, to restrict the users to navigate only onspecific sheets.
The source Pivot table is on the sheet "Menus" where I use the trigger `Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)` to trigger the sheet selection.
I have a copy of the Slicer on each of the target sheets (6).

The problem is, whenever I click on the slicer to go to a different sheet, it calculates the whole file when refreshing the pivot table, and because it's a large file, selecting  the sheets has become super slow.

Is there a programatic way to restrict this so the pivot table only updates to what the slicer shows, withouth affecting the rest of the file?

```
Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    If isThisWbActiveWb Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        Menus_Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate Target
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Every time you select an item in a slicer the pivot table refreshes... You could use the `.ManualUpdate` property and set it to `True` select the sheet and set it back to `False` but still gonna freeze your file refreshing the data. If you want to "hide" sheets from the users, you could just set them to `.Visible = xlVeryHidden` so it can only be shown from visual basic.

Comment: @Damian my boss really likes the interface, because it looks clean. I did present some much faster alternatives like a Toolbar object, but you cannot change the button color, so they will remain grey. We used to use simple buttons, but for some unknown reason, they individually grew randomly in size, even though they were grouped together.

Comment: You could resize them upon pressing. Using slicer will have speed problems the larger the data source gets. You can, like I said, pause this until the sheet is selected, but once selected the pivottable will refresh.